# "symmetrical" rows detection in matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have integer matrix  `A (nA x c)`  with even number of columns (e.g. `mod(c,2) = 0`) and unique rows.
How to effectively (by speed and memory optimized function `symmetricRows`) find  the "symmetrical" rows of matrix `A`, `iA1` and `iA2`, where "symmetric" rows `iA1` and `iA2` are defined as:

```
all(A(iA1,1:end/2) == A(iA2,end/2+1:end) & A(iA1,end/2+1:end) == A(iA2,1:end/2),2) = true
```

Example ():

```
A = [1 1 1 1; 
     2 2 2 2; 
     1 2 3 4;
     4 3 2 1; 
     2 2 3 3; 
     3 4 1 2;  
     3 3 2 2]
[iA1, iA2] = symmetricRows(A)
iA1 =
        1
        2
        3
        5       
iA2 =
        1
        2
        6
        7
```

Typical size of matrices `A`: `nA ~ 1e4 to 1e6`, `c ~ 60 to 120`

The problem is motivated by pre-processing of large dataset, where "symmetrical" rows are irrelevant from the point of user defined distance metric.

Example 2: to prepare larger test data set is possible to use this [function](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb-varargin) and then, for example:

```
N = 10;    
A = allcomb([1:N],[1:N],[1:N],[1:N]);
iA = symmetricRows(A)
```

Comment: For a matrix with 1e6 rows, you're talking about a number of results on the order of 1e12 or a TiB of data. When memory requirements get this large, you really have to question whether you need *all* of that data, and if you do, whether you need it all at once or if you can process it in chunks.

Comment: @beaker Yes, I agree. Any idea how to effectively process it in chunks?

Comment: That depends on how your matrices are being generated, and how they're being used later. Is it possible to generate the matrices such that the first half of each row is lexicographically less than the second half (possibly with an extra flag to indicate that the columns have been swapped)? Once you have the matrix, are you going to process all of the pairs at once, or process all of the rows equivalent to row 1, then rows equivalent to row 2 (or the next unprocessed row)? Is there any other information you have that would indicate where logical groupings would occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the Statistics Toolbox:

```
d = ~pdist2(A(:,1:end/2), A(:,end/2+1:end));
[iA1, iA2] = find(triu(d & d.'));
```

Comment: Nice!!!! Moreover, A could be transformed to the single class, so memory requirements is possible to minimize

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with implicit expansion to create a 3D matrix of comparisons, if you have enough memory.

```
AL = A(:,1:end/2);
AR = A(:,end/2+1:end);
AcompLR = squeeze( all( AL == reshape( AR.', 1, 2, [] ), 2 ) ); 
AcompRL = squeeze( all( reshape( AL.', 1, 2, [] ) == AR, 2 ) ); 

[iA(:,1), iA(:,2)] = find( AcompLR & AcompRL );
iA = unique( sort(iA,2), 'rows' );
```

This returns `iA` where column 1 is your `iA1` and column 2 is your `iA2`.

Note that I needed the `unique` to avoid reversed matches i.e. `[5,7]/[7,5]`

I've not done any benchmarking, but this might be quicker than looping as it is all done in single operations. We could instead be clever about the indexing, and do only the necessary comparisons, this would save memory and a call to `unique`:

```
% Create row indices to cover all combinations of rows
rIdx = arrayfun( @(x) [ones(x,1)*x,(1:x).'], 1:size(A,1), 'uni', 0 );
rIdx = vertcat( rIdx{:} );
% Logical indexing comparisons
iA = rIdx( all( A( rIdx(:,1), 1:end/2 ) == A( rIdx(:,2), end/2+1:end ), 2 ) & ...
           all( A( rIdx(:,2), 1:end/2 ) == A( rIdx(:,1), end/2+1:end ), 2 ), : );
```

Comment: You are right ... your 2nd method is OK, but for size(A,1) ~ 3e4 I am always out of memory. I need more clever trick, but I am not sure if some exist at all :)

Comment: You could use the same approach, but loop through `rIdx` and only store indices where the condition is true. This will take slightly longer, but should be more memory efficient. Unless creating `rIdx` is where you run out of memory, in which case you need to do everything in a loop

Comment: Colud you a bit elaborate you last suggestion (loop through rIdx )? I am not sure if I understand well to your idea.